# Json Edit From Bot

Tags: python, discord.py

When the desired numbers are written with the test command, it passes to json.

[image]

then using the test1 command, number3 needs to change but the whole line is changing

[image]

```
@bot.command()
    async def test(ctx, number1: str, number2: str, number3: str):
        with open('data/data.json', 'r') as f:
             data = json.load(f)
             data[str(ctx.guild.id)] = {
                 'number1': number1,
                 'number2': number2,
                 'number3': number3
             }
    
        with open('data/data.json', 'w') as f:
             json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    
    @bot.command()
    async def test1(ctx, number1: str):
        with open('data/data.json', 'r') as f:
             data = json.load(f)
             data[str(ctx.guild.id)] = {
                 'number1': number1
             }
        with open('data/data.json', 'w',)as f:
             json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Don't post text as image

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
data[str(ctx.guild.id)] = {
    'number1': number1
}
```

will assign a new dictionary, `{ 'number1': number1 }`, to that `"714235..."` field of `data`, so the original dictionary (that contained `number1, number2, number3`) will be gone and garbage collected.

Did you mean to change *the single* `"number1"` key?

```
data[str(ctx.guild.id)]['number1'] = number1
```